# Is it possible to check for a verb without creating my own database?

Tags: c#, string

I am playing around with a sentence string entry for a project I'm working on in C# and wanted to see if there was an alternative way to search for a verb using a built in function.

Currently, I am using a database table with a list of regular verbs and cycling through those to check if there is a match but wanted to see if there would be a better way to do this?

Consider the following input:

"Develop string matching software for verb"

Program will read the string and check each word,

```
if (word == isVerb)
    {
        m_verbs.Add(word);
    }
```

Comment: Are you specifically asking whether you can store the verbs elsewhere of if C# has string functions? Yes to both!

Comment: Is it appropriate for you to use a dictionary web service? How are you going to accommodate words that are both verbs and nouns?

Comment: Note, that depending on context the same string can be a verb or have some other function. You cannot achieve perfect accuracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer :**

There is a better way.

**Long answer :**

It's not that simple. The problem is that there is no inbuilt language functionality into the string class in C#. This is an implementation detail that rests on the developer's shoulders.

You have some grammatical (or perhaps lexical is a better word) issues to consider as Owen79 pointed out in his comment. Then there is the question of environment / resource restrictions.

You have a few options available to you :

- Web based dictionary services. You can query those with the words of your sentence and get back the 'status' of each word. Then you will take only the statuses you want, like verbs for instance. Here is a link to [DictService](http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/) which also includes a C# code sample.
- A text / xml / other file based solution. Similar approach, you simply look up the words in the file and act according to the presence or absence of the word in the file. You can cache (load into memory) the contents of the file to save on IO operations. Here are the links to lists of [regular](http://www.englishclub.com/vocabulary/regular-verbs-list.htm) and [irregular](http://www.englishclub.com/vocabulary/irregular-verbs.htm) verbs.
- Database solution is identical to the previous one with the exception of loading contents into memory. That part may be unnecessary but that depends on your implementation requirements.

Bottom line each solution will require some work but whatever option you go for the key aspects to consider are the platform and the resources available to you. If computational speed is a concern you will most likely need to do some tricks to cut down on lookup times etc.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

you could load the common verbs from disk in a text file. If you have lots of verbs and worry about memory you could bucket them into common and uncommon or alphabetically then load in the dictionaries if needed

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the databse option (although *highly recommanded*), then you need to put them in a data structure (e.g. array or list). You can then use powerful `System.Linq` extension methods.

For example:

```
string[] allVerbs = new[] { "eat", "drink" }; // etc
string s = "Develop string matching software for verb";
var words = s.Split(' ');
foreach (var word in words)
    if (allVerbs.Contains(word.ToLower()))
       m_verbs.Add(word);
```

Comment: Okay, so the database option is a good idea? It seems the better way as I can pick and chose the verbs that I want to be used within the software I suppose. I've not needed to do this before so didn't know if I was missing a trick somewhere.

Comment: Database is considered to be robust, efficient, reliable and fast data source. `SQL` language is designed to make your life much easier, just writing some semi-English sentences to accomblish you the required task. This is much better than re-inventing the wheel